# Understanding how the reduce() function works

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am just ensuring that I know how this function works.  I read material and watched videos on the reduce function for probably 3 hours last night, I did not get it.  I stepped away from my computer, made some food, watched a TV show, and then looked at the computer again and BAM! I got it.  I know how the reduce function works now.

I just don't know why the first example below works while the second doesn't.

source: [Eloquent Javascript Ch. 5 §Flattening](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_aIOczlLyX1)

This works:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

var flattened = arrays.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});

flattened; //=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I tried to fiddle around with the code, to change the variable to a function.  And somehow, I broke it.  This below returns `undefined`, and I am not sure why.

This doesn't work:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

function flattened(arr){
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  });
}
flattened(arrays); //=> undefined
```

Why does the first function work, but not the second?  I'm sure it's something small I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function `flattened` doesn’t return anything.

```
function flattened(arr){
  /* “return” needs to be here */ arr.reduce(function(a, b) { // No return from the outer wrapper function “flattened”
    return a.concat(b); // return from the inner function “reduce”
  });
}
```

The function within it does return something, but the containing function doesn’t.

Comment: Ah that makes sense!! Thanks! I am relatively new to JS, but I am learning fast.  Simple process things like that mix me up at times.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` from the `flattened` function.

```
function flattened(arr){
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So just for my understanding... in my 'broken' example, I returned the concat to the reduce function, but I did not return the reduce function to the flattened function?

Comment: @jward01 Didn’t return the *result* of the `reduce`/`concat`, not `reduce`/`concat` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The flattened() needs to return the value like this:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

function flattened(arr){
return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
}
flattened(arrays);
```